# Adding Incrementing Variable to Id of Html Select

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm running into some issues when trying to access the value of the select in my Html form. There are multiple dropdowns and I am attempting to iterate over them to check for their values. I have tried appending my incrementing variable to the end, but it is not being read out in my call to my js function checkform().

```html
<select id="selectcell<?php echo $i;?>"
 style="WIDTH: 100px; HEIGHT: 20px" type="text" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

**Checkform()**

```js
function checkform(){
 var a=document.getElementById("selectcell<?php echo $i;?>");
 alert(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

Comment: not good with raw js, but can you use getElementById with a wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server side so the php value will only be set once.You have to use javascript to loop the id's.

```
function checkform()
{
    for (i = 1; i < <?php echo $MaxValueOfSelects+1); ?>; i++)
    {
        var a=document.getElementById("selectcell"+i);
        alert(a.options[a.selectedIndex].value);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked perfectly